pixel error when adding a constant vertical line
UPDATE: See Davide's comment; there is no glitch. It's bad code. As soon as I set the line to 0 instead of 100, it worked as expected.
When I create a bar plot without any axis, only adding a constant vertical line using the rule mark, there seems to be a glitch regarding the alignment.
Can this be fixed?
My spec:
{
"width": 200,
"height": 200, 
"params": [
  
  {"name": "colGood", "value": "#1b9e77"},
  {"name": "colBad", "value": "#7570b3"}
],
"data": {"name": "thedata",
    "values": [
      {"region": "Europe" , "Act": 11000, "PY": 9000, "Plan": 10000},
      {"region": "Asia" , "Act": 17000, "PY": 16000, "Plan": 18000},
      {"region": "Americas" , "Act": 19000, "PY": 14000, "Plan": 12000},
      {"region": "Australia" , "Act": 13000, "PY": 14000, "Plan": 12000}
    ]
  },
"transform": [
  {"calculate": "datum['Act'] - datum['Plan']" , "as": "deltaAct_Plan"},
  {"calculate": "datum['deltaAct_Plan'] >= 0 ? datum['Act'] - datum['deltaAct_Plan'] : datum['Act']" , "as": "deltaAct_Plan_Start"},
  {"calculate": "datum['deltaAct_Plan'] > 0 ? datum['Act'] : datum['Plan']" , "as": "deltaAct_Plan_End"},
  {"calculate": "(datum['Act'] / datum['Plan']) - 1" , "as": "deltaAct_Plan_Perc"}
],
"layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "height": {"band": 0.8}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "region", "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
              "title": null,
              
              "labels": false,
              "domain": false,
              "ticks": false,
              "grid": false
          }
        },
        "x": {"field": "deltaAct_Plan", "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": null ,
            "domain": false,
            "grid": false}
        },
        "color": {"value": {"expr": "datum['deltaAct_Plan'] < 0 ? colBad : colGood"}}
      }
    },
    { "description": "the horzontal line called y-axis",
      "mark": { 
        "type": "rule", 
        "color": "darkgrey", 
        "size": 1 },
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 100}}
    }
]
}

I highlighted the  "pixel error" using snagit-arrows.


You have placed the line at 100 and it seems positioned correctly to me. Where are you expecting the line to be? I don't see any glitch?

Hey Davide, you are absolutely spot on, I was staring at this for almost 90min
What do I do now, with my silly qustion?
